# Can I compare a category slug in wordpress to a page title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a structured my blog posts to have categories, and the slugs of these categories are identical to some custom-post post titles.

I want to run a link from the post to the custom-post page using these matching slugs.

In single.php I am trying to run this code... but instead of returning the information of the **custom-post** it returns the information of the **current post**

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
            foreach( $categories as $category ) {
                $current_slug = $category->slug;
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'community',
                        'name' => $current_slug
                    );
                    $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) {
                         the_title( sprintf( '<h3 class="post-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>');
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    }
            }
        }

?>
```

My hope for this code was -> if a post is given a category with the slug: 'cat-one' then at the top of the post would be a link to the CAT ONE page (which is a custom post type page with a url ..../communities/cat-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should absolutely be possible. There's a few issues with your code however, and I've cleaned up a few other things.

You've got the code set up to loop through the categories, but you're using `name` in your `WP_Query()` args, and don't have a loop set up for the results. According to the [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) docs, `name` will return a single post - if you want more than one, (since WP 4.4) you can use `post_name__in` instead. Also, and namely the larger issue with your code, is that you're never set up the internal variables inside your `$cat_query`. I've also added a `while` loop so it will spit out multiple category links.

Without defining the internal variables with the [`$query->the_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/) method (or passing a `$post_id` argument to them), the post variable functions like [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) and [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) will use the current post, which is what your'e seeing now.

This should get you started:

```
if( $categories = get_the_category() ){
    foreach( $categories as $category ){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'community',
            'post_name__in' => $category->slug
        );
        $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $cat_query->have_posts() ){
            while( $cat_query->have_posts() ){
                $cat_query->the_post();

                the_title( sprintf( '<h3 class="post-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>');
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
}
```